# How to migrate customer related data from magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9, database, migration

I am new to magento. I want to update new customer related data from version 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.8. no idea what are table should be move.

Comment: i think simple export customer data and and import latest version customer

Comment: Admin panel:-
Customers->Mange Customers only have export option. There is no import option

Comment: System-> Import/Export -> Export -> Enitity Type: customer

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
same as i need to migrate customer purchased Sales,Invoice,Order data. any idea on that.